# Unable to pass dynamic value to window.open

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

This code works as i have hardcoded "cmp4" but i needed it to be dynamic. When i pass it from a variable it doesn't work. window.open is a js function so I am not sure with R how it takes. It would be great if the solution is in js or R.
I want to pass like this: variable as<- "cmp4" instead of hardcoding it manually

output$createdash<- renderUI({

```
actionButton("sj", "Create Dashboard",

             onclick="window.open('http://192.168.63.198:3838/DS?screen=repdash&portfolio=COMP0004','_self')"

             ,style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
```

})

Comment: Where woud this variable come from? From a `textInput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript ,

assuming u are taking "http://192.168.63.198:3838/DS?screen=repdash&portfolio=COMP0004  " dynamically from browser .  you can split it and take the last element of an array without the need to hardcode it.

lets say browser url is reflecting `"http://192.168.63.198:3838/DS?screen=repdash&portfolio=COMP0004`  since the last element has " =" , we can split based on this

```
const url = window.location.href
let tempArr = url.split("=")


// Approach 1 : getting the last COMP0004 dynamically from url
result = ""
for(let i = 0 ; i < tempArr.length;i++){
  if(i === tempArr.length - 2){
    result = tempArr[i];
    break
  }
}



//Approach 2 : appending COMP0004  to window.open()
function appenurl(c){
let result = ""
for(let i = 0 ; i < tempArr.length;i++){
  result += tempArr[i] + "="
  
  // getting the last element 
  if(i === tempArr.length - 2){
    result += c; 
    break
  }
}
return result;
}

onclick="window.open("+ appendurl("COMP0004") +",_self)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the approach below help? It shows how you can use an input or reactive within `paste0` inside an `actionButton` created with `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("url",
                "Choose URL:",
                choices = c("google" = "http://www.google.com",
                            "amazon" = "http://www.amazon.com")),
    uiOutput("action")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$action <- renderUI({
      
      actionButton("sj", "Create Dashboard",
                   
                   onclick=paste0("window.open('", input$url,"','_self')"),
                   
                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
      
    })
  }
)
```